# Automatically decline all marriage proposition to my widowed mother

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Our previous incarnation died young at the age of 21 years old due to cancer and possibly due to the now hanged Court Physician cutting his Excalibur off in his treatment. Our previous incarnation left a young wife of 27 years old, me (7), my older sister (13) and my little sister (5).

Following our father's footstep, we ascended to the throne of Roman Empire.

Since mother is still young, many tried to court her. As the emperor of the Roman Empire I take this as an insult towards our royal family, my sisters, and me personally.

Is there a way to automatically tell everyone that our mother **is not** available for marriage? Or our only option is to send a decline letter to all the nobles in the land that tries to court her?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no UI method to auto-ignore marriage proposals. Also, you should seriously consider to just give in and find a powerful new husband for her. An unmarried female family member is just an unused resource. As long as she doesn't hold any personal claims to any of your titles or is in any lines of succession, there is no risk in marrying her away. And even then those risks can be largely mitigated by marrying her to someone inside your empire.

But if you really don't want her to marry, you can betroth her to some little boy. That will stop the marriage proposals until the boy is an adult. Then he / his liege will start spamming you with requests to honor the betrothal and marry, but you can still just ignore them. If you later change your mind and want to marry her in a beneficial way, you can break the betrothal. But note that this costs you a bit prestige and gives you an opinion penalty with the other side of the betrothal.

Comment: If there is no UI for that then manual decline is ok. It just feels weird if the former empress dowager marry lesser nobles.

Comment: @絢瀬絵里 *Former* is the keyword here. In the world of Crusader Kings, she is just the dead emperor's baby-maker. But she is *also* a close relative to an emperor, so marrying her means to gain a very powerful ally. That makes her appear like quite a bargain.

Comment: Whoops, I mean the current empress dowager.

Comment: It might be worth noting that, assuming the empress is a Christian, you may be able to use the Order to take Vows Interaction on the dowager empress to have her become a Nun, at that point nobody will try to marry her ever again.